# Odoo - init function is not working

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am working in a sample module and i am creating a view in which i wanted to display record based on criteria and from multiple models. Which are already being created.

**`Pending Accounts`**

```py
class PendingAccounts(models.Model):
    _name = 'amgl.pending_accounts'
    _description = 'Pending Account'

    name = fields.Char()
    first_name = fields.Char(string="First Name")
    last_name = fields.Char(string="Last Name")
    quantity_expected = fields.Float(string="Quantity Expected")
    quantity_received = fields.Float(string="Quantity Received")
    possible_reason = fields.Many2one('amgl.product_reason',string='Possible Reason')
    possible_solution = fields.Many2one('amgl.product_solution', string='Possible Solution')
    notes = fields.Html(string='Notes')

    @api.model_cr
    def init(self):
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(self._cr, 'pending_accounts')
        self._cr.execute("""
            CREATE VIEW pending_accounts AS (
                SELECT c.name AS first_name,
                c.last_name AS last_name,
                o.total_received_qty AS quantity_received,
                o.total_qty AS quantity_expected
                FROM amgl_order AS o
                INNER JOIN amgl_customer AS c ON c.id = o.customer_id
                WHERE o.is_pending = True
            )""")
```

**`Pending Accounts View`**

```xml
<odoo>
<data>
    <record id="amgl.pending_accounts_action_window" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Pending Accounts</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">amgl.pending_accounts</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            <!-- Add Text Here -->
          </p><p>
            <!-- More details about what a user can do with this object will be OK -->
          </p>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record id="amgl.pending_accounts_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Pending Accounts Form</field>
        <field name="model">amgl.pending_accounts</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Pending Inventories">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="first_name"/>
                        <field name="last_name"/>
                        <field name="quantity_expected"/>
                        <field name="quantity_received"/>
                        <field name="possible_reason"/>
                        <field name="possible_solution"/>
                        <field name="notes"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="amgl.pending_accounts_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Pending Account</field>
        <field name="model">amgl.pending_accounts</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Pending Accounts">
                <field name="first_name"/>
                <field name="last_name"/>
                <field name="quantity_expected"/>
                <field name="quantity_received"/>
                <field name="possible_reason"/>
                <field name="possible_solution"/>
                <field name="notes"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
</odoo>
```

So i created a model and added query to get all those records in `init` method of model. But its not showing any records in tree view.I also run the query in pgadmin and there is a records coming against this query as shown in attachment.
[image]

I am facing following error now,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 827, in 
    search_read
    return self.do_search_read(model, fields, offset, limit, domain, sort)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 849, in 
    do_search_read
    offset=offset or 0, limit=limit or False, order=sort or False)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/odoo/models.py", line 4681, in search_read
    records = self.search(domain or [], offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/odoo/models.py", line 1518, in search
    res = self._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/odoo/models.py", line 4242, in _search
    self._cr.execute(query_str, where_clause_params)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/odoo/sql_db.py", line 141, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/ahsan/v10/odoo/sql_db.py", line 218, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
    ProgrammingError: column amgl_pending_accounts.id does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT "amgl_pending_accounts".id FROM "amgl_pending_account...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the following method.

```py
class PendingAccounts(models.Model):
    _name = 'amgl.pending_accounts'
    _description = 'Pending Account'
    _auto=False

    name = fields.Char()
    first_name = fields.Char(string="First Name")
    last_name = fields.Char(string="Last Name")
    quantity_expected = fields.Float(string="Quantity Expected")
    quantity_received = fields.Float(string="Quantity Received")
    possible_reason = fields.Many2one('amgl.product_reason',string='Possible Reason')
    possible_solution = fields.Many2one('amgl.product_solution', string='Possible Solution')
    notes = fields.Html(string='Notes')

    @api.model_cr
    def init(self):
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(self._cr, 'amgl_pending_accounts')
        self._cr.execute("""
            CREATE VIEW amgl_pending_accounts AS (
                SELECT                 
                min(o.id) as id,
                c.name AS first_name,
                c.last_name AS last_name,

                sum(o.total_received_qty) AS quantity_received,
                sum(o.total_qty) AS quantity_expected
                FROM amgl_order AS o
                INNER JOIN amgl_customer AS c ON c.id = o.customer_id
                WHERE o.is_pending = True
                Group By c.name,c.last_name
            )""")
```

> **_auto=False** : Determines whether a corresponding PostgreSQL table must be generated automatically from the object. Setting _auto to
>   False can be useful in case of OpenERP objects generated from
>   PostgreSQL views. See the "Reporting From PostgreSQL Views" section
>   for more details.
>
> You must take **min(o.id) as id** in select query other wise it will give
>   you Error.
>
> Your **view name & table name** must be equal **amgl_pending_accounts** .
>
> Update your query and add missing fields by joining those tables, then
>   your error will be fixed.

This may help you.

Comment: i think its not working also because now i am getting error on next field `ProgrammingError: column amgl_pending_accounts.possible_solution does not exist
LINE 1: ...amgl_pending_accounts"."last_name" as "last_name","amgl_pend...`

Comment: First issue was there because of ID field, now give me complete error, I will tell you the reason

Comment: Please review updated answer, there was mistake in my query. I forgot to mention group by.

Comment: You need to restart server and upgrade module.

Comment: Thats such a crapy thing. Should i include `possible_reason,possible_solution` in query because they are in model but not in query as i am getting this error now `ProgrammingError: column amgl_pending_accounts.possible_solution does not exist
LINE 1: ...amgl_pending_accounts"."last_name" as "last_name","amgl_pend...`

Comment: Whatever fields you have declared all fields must be returned form the query that's the rule.

Comment: You need to update your query or remove those fields from the declaration.

Comment: But in my case these fields are not stored yet in database so i cannot retrieve them. I added them because when user edit the records in pending accounts then he will be able to add reason or solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149389/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-ancient).

Comment: ok its working now seems like i need to remove those fields . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use *_auto=False* to execute *init()* method.

Whether a database table should be created (default: True)

If set to False, override init() to create the database table.

**EDIT**

In such cases, first we need to drop table permanently from the database. Go to your terminal and follow below commands:

```
sudo su postgres
psql <YourDatabaseName>
DROP TABLE amgl_pending_accounts CASCADE;
\q
```

Now refresh web browser and upgrade module.

Comment: Now i am getting `ProgrammingError: relation "amgl_pending_accounts" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "amgl_pending_accounts".id FROM "amgl_pending_account...
` when i access tree view

Comment: This view will not store in database. Everytime it will load fresh one. So we need to drop previous one and load/create fresh one. You may review *init()* method in *report* folder in *sale* module. File name is *sale_report.py*

Comment: I am not saying about view, i was asking about table because pending_accounts table was already created when `_auto=False` was not there. Also i tried the same way its done in other models, `sale_report,sale_history` and many other. But its not working may be there is some thing i am missing.

Comment: Just drop the table and init always drop the view before creating it

Comment: @CherifOdoo i tried dropping table then i get above error. Which i showed in above comment and that error occurs when i land on tree view

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you define _name = 'amgl.pending.acounts'

odoo excpect that the name of the table in database is: amgl_pending_accounts
try this. just understand that (.) will be (_) in table name.

```
class PendingAccounts(models.Model):
            _name = 'amgl.pending.accounts'
            _description = 'Pending Account'
                        _auto = False

            name = fields.Char()
            first_name = fields.Char(string="First Name")
            last_name = fields.Char(string="Last Name")
            quantity_expected = fields.Float(string="Quantity Expected")
            quantity_received = fields.Float(string="Quantity Received")
            possible_reason = fields.Many2one('amgl.product_reason',string='Possible Reason')
            possible_solution = fields.Many2one('amgl.product_solution', string='Possible Solution')
            notes = fields.Html(string='Notes')

            @api.model_cr
            def init(self):
                tools.drop_view_if_exists(self._cr, 'pending_accounts')
                self._cr.execute("""
                    CREATE VIEW amgl_pending_accounts AS (

                        SELECT 
                        -- by default view expect the id columns to exists.
                        row_number() OVER () AS id,
                        c.name AS first_name,
                        c.last_name AS last_name,
                        o.total_received_qty AS quantity_received,
                        o.total_qty AS quantity_expected
                        FROM amgl_order AS o
                        INNER JOIN amgl_customer AS c ON c.id = o.customer_id
                        WHERE o.is_pending = True
                    )""")
```

XML:

```xml
    <odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="amgl.pending.accounts_action_window" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Pending Accounts</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">amgl.pending.accounts</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
              <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                <!-- Add Text Here -->
              </p><p>
                <!-- More details about what a user can do with this object will be OK -->
              </p>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record id="amgl.pending.accounts_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Pending Accounts Form</field>
            <field name="model">amgl.pending.accounts</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Pending Inventories">
                    <sheet>
                        <group>
                            <field name="first_name"/>
                            <field name="last_name"/>
                            <field name="quantity_expected"/>
                            <field name="quantity_received"/>
                            <field name="possible_reason"/>
                            <field name="possible_solution"/>
                            <field name="notes"/>
                        </group>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="amgl.pending.accounts_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Pending Account</field>
            <field name="model">amgl.pending.accounts</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Pending Accounts">
                    <field name="first_name"/>
                    <field name="last_name"/>
                    <field name="quantity_expected"/>
                    <field name="quantity_received"/>
                    <field name="possible_reason"/>
                    <field name="possible_solution"/>
                    <field name="notes"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
    </odoo>
```

Comment: No its still same error. why it only gives error when i load tree view , not in form view and also if you see query in error its trying to get records from `amgl_pending_accounts` and that table is no more.

Comment: what about `_auto = False` ?

Comment: That is the most important thing yes i forget it

Comment: I updated model with your code and right now i am facing this error : `ProgrammingError: column amgl_pending_accounts.id does not exist  LINE 1: SELECT "amgl_pending_accounts".id FROM "amgl_pending_account...`

Comment: see my question update i also added complete trace of error

Comment: Ok i can see your problem you are missing the id column edit your query to generate an auto increment virtual id. check my edits

Comment: remove the comment when you run the code please or change # by --

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your select query it will resolve the problem :

Select row_number() OVER () as id , customer_id ................
AND
in your model add customer_id = fields.Many2one(amgl_customer,'customer')